# How to utilize a required (scoped) service when using AddAuthentication during ConfigureServices in ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Inside my ASP.NET Core 3.0 `ConfigureServices` method (`Startup` class) I need to add authentication on a variety of third-party identity providers (IdPs) -- and I store that information in a database.

I add the database repository as a **scoped** service and then have defined an extension method that uses that repo to look up IdP configuration and add additional IdPs to the authentications of the applications.

The code below **works**, but I'm getting a warning about additional instances of singletons being created due to the use of `BuildServiceProvider()`.

I'm wondering if there is a better approach for me to add these database-stored IdPs into the authentication mix without incurring these duplicates.

```
services.AddScoped<IIdentityServerRepository, IdentityServerRepository>();

var issuerUri = _config.GetValue<string>("MyIssuerUri");

var identityRepo = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IIdentityServerRepository>();
services.AddAuthentication()
   .AddIdentityProviders(identityRepo, issuerUri);
```

Here is some (not all) of the extension method class where `AddIdentityProviders` is defined:

```
public static class IdentityProviderHelper
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddIdentityProviders(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, 
        IIdentityServerRepository repo, string issuerUri)
    {
        builder.AddAzureAdProvider(repo);
        builder.AddOpenIdConnectProviders(repo);
        builder.AddSamlProviders(repo, issuerUri);
        return builder;
    }

    private static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdProvider(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, IIdentityServerRepository repo)
    {
        var azureConfig = repo.GetProviderConfigurationByName(ProviderEnum.AzureActiveDirectory).FirstOrDefault();
        if (azureConfig == null) return builder;

        return builder.AddOpenIdConnect(azureConfig.AuthenticationType, azureConfig.Description, options => SetOidcOptions(azureConfig, options));
    }

...
}
```

Comment: Where does the `AddIdentityProviders` method come from?

Comment: It's my own extension method.  I can provide sample code if it helps -- it just uses the repo to grab some data and then calls methods like AddOpenIdProvider() or other such.